What is this Jeppesen approach plate symbol?

What is this “VVV” symbol circles on the plan view?

I can't find a reference for it in the symbology reference, but I'm pretty sure it indicates a route segment that can't be shown to scale.
The plan area is to scale, but the 5nm hold can't be shown entirely within the  chart.  So the hold racetrack is shrunk to fit and the route compression symbol indicates that it's no longer shown exactly.
The FAA charts have a similar symbol.


The FAA symbol is clearer and the more common version (at least, in general graphing; I’m not familiar with aeronautics). You’d also think they should include that symbol on both sides of the oval, since if you go out 5 nm you have to come back from 5 nm out and that’s also not drawn to scale. It’d help figure out from context what the symbol means, too—I rejected that interpretation because the other leg didn’t have it.
